# Keeping one section open at a time in UITableView based accordion view based on apple sample code TVAnimationsGestures

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm building an app with a UITableView-based accordion view. This code is based on Apple sample code which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/TVAnimationsGestures_main_m.html) or [here](https://github.com/lesyk/TVAnimationsGestures-ios-4.3).
In the sample code, the problem I'm trying to fix is there, so I know that it's not something that I introduced.

If you open multiple sections without closing the previous one explicitly, multiple sections can be open at the same time. This can lead to a crash, which can be replicated by hitting buttons 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3.

In my app, I am trying to make the previous section close and the button in the header go to an unselected state when a new section is opened, so that you can only ever have one section opened and one section header button selected at a time. If anyone has any experience with this sample code or this use of a tableview, I'd love to correct this, especially since it's a problem inherent in Apple's own code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property APLSectionHeaderView* headerView of APLSectionInfo is never set.
So set `sectionInfo.headerView = sectionHeaderView` in tableView delegate method.

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    APLSectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

    APLSectionInfo *sectionInfo = (self.sectionInfoArray)[section];

    sectionHeaderView.titleLabel.text = sectionInfo.play.name;
    sectionHeaderView.section = section;
    sectionHeaderView.delegate = self;
    sectionInfo.headerView = sectionHeaderView;
    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed the issue completely