# How to close another expanded section when second Section is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am creating an app that contain the expandable section. I have implemented that using [this](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/) tutorial.

But now i want to close first expanded section when i clicked another section. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Just remove everything from the list of expanded sections whenever you expand a section...

Comment: Maybe you could use an int where you store the value of the opened section. When a section is clicked, you change this value, and in the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you return 0 or your number of row depending of if the section equals to your stored number of section

Answer (score 0):

You can move the logic code in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to a new method (`switchSection`) and call it on the expanded section to collapse it before expanding the new section. Note that you don't need `expandedSections` set anymore as you'll have only one section expanded.

```
NSUInteger expandedSection; /// Define this instead of expandedSections

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section]) {
        if (!indexPath.row) {
            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = (expandedSection == section);

            /// Collapse expanded section
            if (expandedSection >= 0) {
                [self switchSection:expandedSection];
            }

            /// Expand the new section if needed
            if (!currentlyExpanded) {
                [self switchSection:section];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)switchSection:(NSInteger)section {
    BOOL currentlyExpanded = (expandedSection == section);
    NSInteger rows;
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (currentlyExpanded) {
        expandedSection = -1;
        rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    } else {
        expandedSection = section;
        rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
    [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (currentlyExpanded) {
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];
    } else {
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        cell.accessoryView =  [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for answer, As you can see in ` for (NSInteger item in expandedSections)` this code expandedSections is `NSMutableIndexSet` so i cant check that item is within it or not at this line it gives me error

Comment: Check the updated answer. You have to define `NSUInteger expandedSection` instead of the index set.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has provided a sample code. Here is the link [TVAnimationGestures](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/TVAnimationsGestures_main_m.html/%22Table%20View%20Animations%20and%20Gestures%22).

But there is a small bug in it please refer [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186040/keeping-one-section-open-at-a-time-in-uitableview-based-accordion-view-based-on/17189631#17189631).